# Constraint model in econometrics?

Tags: statistics, regression

Let's consider this simple regression model
$$y_i = β_0 + β_1x_i + u_i$$
where the Gauss-Markov hypotheses are met. Suppose we know that $β_0=0$

a) Write the constraint model (assuming $β_0=0$) et write the sum of squares associated with this model.

b) Find the first order conditions et the OLS estimator for $β_1$ in this model.

My issues here is that I can't seem to find what a constraint model is. I do not believe it was taught in my class and I can't find anything online. Thank you.

Comment: Here the constraint is $\beta_0=0$.  Other constraints are possible

Comment: @Henry So the answer is in the question? I feel like that's not what they're asking though

Comment: Writing $y_i = β_1x_i + u_i$ is just the first part of (a).  You still have to do the second part of (a) plus the two parts of (b)

Comment: @Henry Aah thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a.2) The sum of squares associated with the constrained model.
$$
S(\beta_1) = \sum_{i=1}^n ( y_i - \beta_1 x_i ) ^2,
$$
b) The first order condition is
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_1} S(\beta_1) \rvert_{ \beta_1 = \hat{\beta}_1 } -2 \sum_{i=1}^n ( y_i - \beta_1 x_i ) = 0
$$

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful !!